# What GPU driver installed?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have problem with my display ->[I have problem with my display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804858/i-have-problem-with-my-display) *I downloaded new my Nvidia GPU's driver version. How I should install it? #Ubuntu14 LTS 64bit

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 04ca
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 04ca
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: You can find drivers in System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver for this adapter in Ubuntu 14.04 is installed this way:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
```

Disable Secure Boot, if UEFI is used.